# Sed script to print a variable based on user input

Tags: bash, sed

I want to write a `sed` script that reads user input, and if the variable matches a predefined string it should print welcome, otherwise it should print sorry.

For example, if user inputs "Hello" the system should print "Welcome", if not it should print "Sorry".

Comment: What have you tried so far? why do you want to use `sed` for this task, specifically? As it stands, this isn't really a question within the terms of this site - please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sed isn't the right tool, use grep

Comment: Are you doing this to get a password?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter some input:" USERINPUT
(grep "$USERINPUT" -q inputfile.txt ) && echo "Welcome" || echo "Sorry"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get input of a password, that is certainly not how to do it.

First, the comparison password should be stored as a hash. Create that with `md5sum` for example:

```
echo hello | md5sum
```

gives

```
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  -
```

Now to get the input, we can [use @Serg's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/635109/186134), slightly modified. We use the `-s` to hide the input (keep it secret).

```
echo Please enter password:
read -s input
```

and compare it to the hash:

```
input=$(echo $input | md5sum)

if [ $input == "b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  -" ]
then
    echo "Welcome, your password was correct"
else
    echo "Sorry, wrong password"
fi
```